# Switch back and forth between filetypes in VIM

Tags: vim

Similar to how spell checking works. I have a custom syntax I wish to temporary apply to any filetype in the buffer. I figure the best way to do this is just change the filetype. But, I don't know how to get back to previous filetype without being explicit. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:filetype detect` to redetect the original filetype.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a `function` and a keyboard map to do it for you, e.g.:

```
function! ToggleFileType()
   if g:my_file_type" == 0
      let ft=MYFILETYPE
      let g:my_file_type = 1
   else
      filetype detect
      let g:my_file_type = 0
   endif
endfunction

nmap <silent>  ;s  :call ToggleFileType()<CR>
```

So this way, hitting <kbd>;</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> (in normal mode) calls the above function, which checks which filetype is set, then toggles.